# Extract string from url in r

Tags: r, string, text-extraction

My dataframe contains a URL field which sometimes contains a 13-digit product identifier. I need to extract this product ID and write it to a new column call ISBN. Below are 3 different URL, each with the product ID positioned differently:

```
>https://catalog.macmillan.com/childrens/book/brazen/rebel-ladies-who-rocked-the-world/pnlope-bagieu/**9781626728691**?utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=na-schoolandlibrary&utm_content=na-discover-nl&utm_campaign=schoolandlibrary
>https://us.macmillan.com/excerpt?isbn=**9781250151025**&utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=na-schoolandlibrary&utm_content=na-discover-nl&utm_campaign=schoolandlibrary
>https://catalog.macmillan.com/childrens/book/so-tall-within/sojourner-truths-long-walk-toward-freedom/gary-d-schmidt/daniel-minter/**9781626728721**?utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=na-schoolandlibrary&utm_content=na-discover-nl&utm_campaign=schoolandlibrary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gregexpr`, assuming that length of product number is always 13, as  shown.

```
regmatches(tx, gregexpr("(\\d{13})", tx))
# [[1]]
# [1] "9781626728691" "9781250151025" "9781626728721"
```

***Data***

```
tx <- "https://catalog.macmillan.com/childrens/book/brazen/rebel-ladies-who-rocked-the-world/pnlope-bagieu/9781626728691?utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=na-schoolandlibrary&utm_content=na-discover-nl&utm_campaign=schoolandlibrary https://us.macmillan.com/excerpt?isbn=9781250151025&utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=na-schoolandlibrary&utm_content=na-discover-nl&utm_campaign=schoolandlibrary https://catalog.macmillan.com/childrens/book/so-tall-within/sojourner-truths-long-walk-toward-freedom/gary-d-schmidt/daniel-minter/9781626728721?utm_source=exacttarget&utm_medium=newsletter&utm_term=na-schoolandlibrary&utm_content=na-discover-nl&utm_campaign=schoolandlibrary"
```

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf, the extraction works fine, but the extracted product ids are placed in a list, not in a field. Here's what I used: data$ISBN<-regmatches(data$URL, gregexpr("(\\d{13})", data$URL)).

Comment: Use `[[ELEMENT_#]]`, or `unlist()` depending on the structure of your url's.. You could also use the same pattern with `stringi`: `stringi::stri_extract_all(tx, regex = "(\\d{13})")[[1]]` or `unlist(stringi::stri_extract_all(tx, regex = "(\\d{13})"))`

Comment: @Andrew I used data["ISBN_take_2"] <- sapply(data$ISBN, paste, collapse = ", ") and then dropped the column that was a list.